# if new feature downgrade the score for xgboost what do I have to look at?

Tags: machine-learning, feature-selection, xgboost, feature-engineering

let say I'm predicting the housing price of Boston(kaggle). 
if I got some score x

then I added new feature  y_K 
if this new feature drop the score.
what is wrong with this feature and what do I have to look at?

if I know this process I can test all my features with this test

Comment: How do you know it dropped your score. Was it dropped in your test dataset? In your training dataset? In both?